# How to list Currently Authorized Views in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, view

I want to list all the Currently Authorized Views in a dataset (projectID, datasetID, and tableID).

I have try to check using Information schema but still face the dead end. I want to gather information about projectID, datasetID, and tableID. Is there any possible way to do it?

Image of Authorized View

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to list [views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-views#scope_and_syntax) in BigQuery, you can use below queries.

To Return metadata for views in a single dataset

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

To Return metadata for all views in a region

```
SELECT * FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

It's not possible to query only the authorized views using INFORMATION_SCHEMA. As per your requirement to view projectID, datasetID, and tableID details of Authorized Views in a dataset, as you have mentioned you can go to your dataset and click + Sharing > Authorize Views where you can add authorization and view the Currently Authorized Views.

[image]

For more information you can refer to this [tutorial](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/42016?parent=catalog).

If you want the feature to view details of  authorized views using  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as present in BigQuery UI, you can raise a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker describing your requirement.

Comment: I have tried the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS but the query can't differentiate whether it's view or authorized views. Maybe I'll try to give feature request to BigQuery. Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the `bq show` command.

`bq show --dataset=true my_dataset_name`

It will output the authorized views in standard BQ syntax: `project_id.dataset_id.table_id`